# Random leader selection after each round

Tags: algorithm, distributed-computing, leader-election

I am working on a system where I need to select a leader(out of n nodes) randomly. The leader would change after each round (after the current leader has finished its task). All the nodes would be communicating with each other.

A re-election would take place in two conditions:

1. The round is finished.
2. The leader dies prematurely.

Are there any implementations of this idea for reference. Is doing so a good idea? Why? Should this situation be approached differently?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. Selecting a random leader from a list is trivially easy: just call your random number generator to get a number between 0 and n. What makes your problem different?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood your question you need to select a different leader from your nodes Everytime so to do this you can put all the nodes in a queue and then find the length of queue and generate a random number from 0 to the queue length and name the node at this index as a leader when he dies or finished it's work you can remove this node from the queue and re elect your leader by the same process.Now the length is 1 less.
Hope I have understood the question correctly.